# How to access implict closure parameters from higher closure level

Tags: swift, arguments, closures

I want to iterate an `enum` and then use $0 in a `switch/case` statement down one level in a closure that is called in a fetch operation inside the `enum` iteration loop, as follows:

```
enum GenericType: CaseIterable {
    case purchase
    case sale
    // etc....
}
```

Then the code to use is as follows:

```
GenericType.allCases.forEach {
    // let type = $0
    Manager.fetchItems(ofType: $0, onSuccess: { (data) in
        switch $0 {
        case purchase:
        // Do something
        case sale:
        // Do something
    }                                               
}
```

Xcode 10 assumes that `$0` refers to `data` (the parameter in the closure) and gives this error message:

```
Anonymous closure arguments cannot be used inside a closure that has explicit arguments; did you mean 'data'?
```

I am able to make it work with before the fetch:

```
let type = $0
```

And then using `type` in the `switch/case` statement.

Is there a way to access the `$0` shorthand argument from the higher level context inside a closure?   Is the workaround a feasible solution?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$0` can only ever refer to the first closure context "up the chain". To access the parameters of outter closures, you need to name them:

```
GenericType.allCases.forEach { genericType in
    Manager.fetchItems(ofType: genericType, onSuccess: { data in
        switch genericType {
        case .purchase: return
            // Do something
        case .sale: return
            // Do something
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot...@Alexander   It is more elegant than naming $0 with a let inside the loop.....    I am accepting it

Comment: @eharo2, by the way, because you are naming each item in `GenericType.allCases` (`genericType in`), I see no reason why not to use a `for in` loop. The benefit is that your code structure is somewhat simpler.

Comment: @Daniel Indeed, I agree. Though I wish there was a better way to model "do something for each case in an Enum". This approach has the benefit of the exclusivity checking, but it causes branching overhead. Unless that's optimized away, which is totally possible.

Comment: @Daniel It does optimize it. Damn impressive. https://godbolt.org/z/EOo0Es

Comment: @Daniel.  I have to use a switch-case inside the forEach loop, because I have different methods to be executed in different manager objects.   I am exploring to make all managers subclass of a SuperManager class with a common overridden method like "processFetchData(), and then add a var manager of type SuperManager to the enum, and then I should be able to do something like: genericType.manager.processFetchData().  The specific code of each subclass would be included inside the common method.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Alexander and @Daniel's answer/inputs, this is the way I implemented the for loop without the `switch-case` statement.

```
enum GenericType: CaseIterable {
    case purchase
    case sale
    var manager: GenericManager {
        switch self {
        case .purchase:
            return PurchaseManager.shared
        case .sale:
            return SalesManager.shared
        }
    }
}
```

`PurchaseManager` and `SaleManager` are subclasses of `GenericManager` and they override the `processFetchData(_:)` method.

And the code is as follows:

```
GenericType.allCases.forEach { genericType in
    FetchManager.fetchItems(ofType: genericType, onSuccess: { data in
        genericType.manager.processFetchData(data)
    })
}
```

Strictly speaking I only moved the `switch` statement from the biz logic to the `enum` declaration, but it makes it a bit more elegant.